# Best way to communicate between left-pane treeviewitem viewmodel and right-pane viewmodel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am new to WPF and MVVM, and would appreciate help with the following problem:

I have a classical windows-explorer type interface, with a treeview in the left pane. Just as in Josh Smith's treeview sample application, the viewmodel of each treeviewitem is notified through 2-way binding whenever it is selected in the view. The user expects to see some information in the right-pane related to the tree node selected in the left pane. For this to happen, the viewmodel for the right-pane needs to be informed by the viewmodel of the selected treeviewitem. Also included in this notification should be the unique identifier of the selected node so that the correct information can be pulled by the right-pane viewmodel from the database. What is the best way for this particular viewmodel-to-viewmodel notification to work?

Possibilities that come to mind are:

1. regular .NET events
2. event aggregation as in PRISM
3. commanding
4. other options that I am not aware of.

Please guide me, what is the best way to implement this communication.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use the Mediator Pattern (e.g. Messenger class from MVVM Light Libs) for such a problem.

```
public class SelectionChangedMessage : MessageBase
{
    public object SelectedItem { get; private set; }
    public string Id { get; private set; }

    public SelectionChangedMessage(object sender, object selectedItem, string id) : base(sender)
    {
        if (selectedItem == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("selectedItem");
        if (id == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("id");
        SelectedItem = selectedItem;
        Id = id;
    }
}
```

Then in your left pane VM:

```
MessengerInstance.Send(new SelectionChangedMessage(this, SelectedItem, SelectedId));
```

In you right pane VM:

```
MessengerInstance.Register<SelectionChangedMessage>(this, msg =>
{
    //Do stuff
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always difficult to answer questions when no code examples have been provided (please remember that for future questions). As it is, all I can do is make assumptions. So, with that in mind, as you have said that *the viewmodel of each treeviewitem is notified through 2-way binding whenever it is selected in the view*, I am going to assume that you have data bound it to the `TreeViewItem.IsSelected` property.

Instead of (or as well as) binding the `TreeViewItem.IsSelected` property to a property of the individual object view model that is in the collection that is data bound to the `TreeView.ItemsSource`, you can bind the `TreeView.SelectedItem` property to a property of the parent view model that contains the collection property:

```
public YourObjectType SelectedItem 
{
    get { return selectedItem; }
    set 
    {
        selectedItem = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItem"); // must implement INPC interface
        LoadObjectFromDatabase(selectedItem.Id);
     }
}
```

This way, whenever this property changes, a `LoadObjectFromDatabase` method can be passed the unique `Id` value of the selected item.